# How can I get information about moving average?

Tags: r, moving-average, rolling-average

I want to calculate moving average for my project. But I don't understand this blew codes. How can get more information about moving average codes?

```r
cx <- c(0, cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)))
cn <- c(0, cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1)))0
rx <- cx[(n+1):length(cx)] - cx[1:(length(cx) - n)]
rn <- cn[(n+1):length(cx)] - cn[1:(length(cx) - n)]
rsum <- rx / rn
```

Comment: Moving average is done well with `zoo::rollmean` or the newer `slider` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is asking to explain the code then it is taking the moving average of length n of the vector x.  For example, if there are no NA's and n=2 then the first few elements of the output are (x[1] + x[2])/2, (x[2] + x[3])/2, etc.

```
n <- 2
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 7, 9)
cx <- c(0, cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)))  # 0  1  4  8 15 24
cn <- c(0, cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1)))  # 0 1 2 3 4 5
rx <- cx[(n+1):length(cx)] - cx[1:(length(cx) - n)]  #  4  7 11 16
rn <- cn[(n+1):length(cx)] - cn[1:(length(cx) - n)]  # 2 2 2 2
rsum <- rx / rn  # 2.0 3.5 5.5 8.0
```

cx is 0 followed by the cumulative sum of x except NA's are replaced with 0
in calculating the cumulative sum.

cn is 0 followed by the cumulative number of non-NA's.

rx is the cumulative sum minus the cumulative sum n positions back.

rn is the number of non-NA's minus the number of non-NAs n positions back.

rsum is the ratio of the last two.